# Python vaex how to create dataframe from a CSV file?

Tags: python, dataframe, vaex

Why do I only get the last column

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
# win远程linux运行
import vaex,pandas as pd
df_pd = pd.read_csv('./a.csv')  # contains 4 columns
print(df_pd)
print(list(df_pd.columns))
df = vaex.from_pandas(df_pd)   # only last column   # why???
print(df)
```

Why do I only get the last column

Comment: could you provide an example so that we can create the csv?

Comment: I see;Column names are automatically deleted when they are in Chinese. My first few columns are in Chinese

Comment: column name could not be chinese;

Answer (score 1):

Vaex replaces non-ascii characters by an underscore, but two underscores means 'hidden' column. We should change that, and I've opened an issue for that:
https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues/558

Answer (score 1):

To create a vaex dataframe out of a csv file.

Try, `vaex.from_csv('a.csv')`

If the dataset is huge and is around billions of data then you might have to use chunk_size in `from_csv` to avoid memory issues.